# How to implement xml serialization for custom types?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have some types that I want to serialize/deserialize and generate a UI based on the selected object. The UI will also change the object which in turn I will have to serialize to store it in my app.

So:

```
[obj_apple stored in the app] -> select obj_apple -> deserialize -> show in UI -> use the UI to change obj_apple -> deselect obj_apple -> serialize -> [obj_apple stored in the app]
```

The objects have to be serialized/deserialized and this data has to be string. That's why I thought having an xml serializer would be better.

Which type of serializer would be the best? And are there any good examples to implement this for custom types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices for strings; xml, which can be done simply with `XmlSerializer` (or `DataContractSerializer`, but that offers much less control over the xml) or JSON (JSON.net, etc).

Typical classes for `XmlSerializer` would look simply like:

```
public class Apple {
    public string Variety {get;set;}
    public decimal Weight {get;set;}
    // etc
}
```

(note I would expect the above to work the JSON.net too)

The above class should also work fine in data-binding scenarios etc, thanks to the properties.

You would serialize this:

```
    Apple obj = new Apple { Variety = "Cox", Weight = 12.1M};
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Apple));

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    ser.Serialize(sw, obj);
    string xml = sw.ToString();

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
    Apple obj2 = (Apple)ser.Deserialize(sr);
```

but you can customize the xml:

```
[XmlType("apple"), XmlRoot("apple")]
public class Apple {
    [XmlAttribute("variety")]
    public string Variety {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("weight")]
    public decimal Weight {get;set;}
    // etc
}
```

`DataContractSerializer` is *ideally* more like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Apple {
    [DataMember]
    public string Variety {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Weight {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Btw Marc, can I use XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(obj.GetType()));

I am just wondering if typeof has an advantage in this case?

Comment: new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

Answer (score 2):

[DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) all day.