# Properties.Settings.Default Custom Listtype is not saved!

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, settings

Hey found out about the settings class Properties.Settings.Default today and saving strings etc. works perfectly fine, though when i want to save a custom List i've created it doesn't work. The list is always null even though there is an entry in the appdata config file with an empty value node.
The list is inherited from the ObservableCollection where blabla has a Size (type size) and name (type string) properties. Can someone help me out?

Comment: i've meant is inherited from ObservableCollectioon<blabla> where blabla has a Size (type size) and name (type string) properties..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added

```
[SettingsSerializeAs(System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
```

to the property in the settings class (Settings.settings):

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[SettingsSerializeAs(System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
public global::TestWpfApplication.EtikettDimensionList Dimensions 
{
    get 
    {
        return ((global::TestWpfApplication.EtikettDimensionList)(this["Dimensions"]));
    }
    set
    {
        this["Dimensions"] = value;
    }
}
```

This will serialize the objects in binary format. If you want XmlFormat you have to implement XML serialization for all classes.

Comment: If you wrote the type there should be a `[Serializable]` attribute on the class. If it is a class from the framework it will be mentioned in the help and finally in all other cases you can use Reflector to inspect the attributes.

Comment: i've set the Serializable Attribute to both the list and 'blabla', still doesn't work!

Comment: `code`public class EtikettDimensionList : ObservableCollection<EtikettDimension>
    { }
    [Serializable]
    public class EtikettDimension
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Size Size { get; set; }

        public EtikettDimension(string name, Size size)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Size = size;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + " " + Size.ToString();
        }
    }`code`

Comment: Got it. See my EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Hey Erno, sorry for the late anwser! Tried it again today and now it works ( with the serializable attribute ). Thanks for the awesome help :)

Comment: Glad to help: please mark this answer as the answer so other can benefit

Comment: hmm, suddenly it doesn't work anymore. a few hours ago the only thing i did is adding the [Serializable] attribute to the 2 classes and everything was fine, then i added another setting and now it just doesn't want to serialize as binary .. 

<setting name="Dimensions" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value />
            </setting>

Any idea what could have caused this?

Comment: The [Serializable] attribute isn't needed when using Binary serialization. If you want xml serialization you will have to implement it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507010/how-to-implement-xml-serialization-for-custom-types

Comment: I dont really need xml serialization. i just want to get back to the binary one. I just don't know how i did it the last time.. where can i find the code u posted in your anwser? where u've added [SettingsSerializeAs(System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]

Comment: It is in the Settings.settings class. You can find it under the properties of the project in the solution explorer

Comment: Great answer. I solve my big problem with a custom settings file which save custom classes in it.